# Login Redirects to Home Page Regardless of Credentials in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've just started to .NET MVC. I'm trying to make a simple login form that inputs username and password. I put a simple condition to user to authorize. If username is admin and password is 123456, it should direct to home page. But regardless of whether the entered credentials are correct or incorrect, the page still directs to the home page.

I tried to clear the cache (idk i thought it may be the cause).

This is my AccountController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace htmlHelperStudy.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // Kullanıcı adı ve şifre kontrolü yapılacak
            if (IsValidUser(username, password))
            {
                // Giriş başarılı, ana sayfaya yönlendir
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                // Giriş başarısız, hata mesajı ile login sayfasını tekrar göster
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                return View();
            }
        }

        // Kullanıcı adı ve şifre kontrolünü gerçekleştiren metot
        private bool IsValidUser(string username, string password)
        {
            // Gerçek bir doğrulama işlemi yapılmalı
            // Bu örnekte basit bir şifre kontrolü örneği:
            return username == "admin" && password == "123456";
        }
    }

}
```

This is my HomeController.cs

```
using htmlHelperStudy.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace htmlHelperStudy.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult RedirectToLogin()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }

 }
```

And this is my Login.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Simple View";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you have  `Home` as controller in `<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Try to  change to `<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">`

Comment: @Orifjon I just can't believe i miss this. It worked fine after changing it.

Comment: Having your Login page redirect to Home page only when the credentials are entered correctly is a good first step. However, it does not make your Home page protected, because the user can navigate directly to the home page and see it, unless you make additional changes, for example, add the [Authorize] attribute, to protect URLs require users to login.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get to see the Home page regardless of credentials entered is that you did not mark the HomeController with [Authorize] attribute.

If you add the [Authorize] attribute, you will not see the home page unless you login. The [Authorize] attribute added to the HomeController will redirect you to the login page when you attempt to navigate to Home page.

Here's one way to do it in your HomeController class:

```cs
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

You may need to configure the app to get the correct redirect to Login page. Your current `RedirectToLogin` method does nothing because it's not called when you navigate to the Home page.